Salesforce User with a certain profile can only delete contact base on Account.field__c and the user.field__c is the same
Salesforce User with a certain profile can only delete contact base on Account.field__c and the user.field__c is the same.
do you guys have any ideas on how to do this. I need the user to delete a record if the contact records Account.field__c is the same as the users field__c. I have tried a validation rule:
I also give the user's profile a delete access on the contact object.
AND(
OR(
$Profile.Name = "HA Customer Care - External/Agents",
$Profile.Name = "HA Customer Care - Internal"
),
TEXT($User.ps_BookingOfficeID__c) != Account.ps_BookingOffice__r.Name
)


Validation rules don't fire on delete, only insert/update. You need a before delete trigger. Or flow.
Something like this (except this is just for answer purposes, a proper "pro" solution would have a separate trigger handler class)
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact(before delete){
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete){
        validateDeletes(trigger.old);
    }
    
    public static void validateDeletes(List<Contact> contacts){
        User u = [SELECT Profile.Name, ps_BookingOfficeID__c
            FROM User
            WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
        // These 2 profiles need extra checks when deleting.
        // Anybody else can delete whatever they need.
        Set<String> restricted = new Set<String>('HA Customer Care - External/Agents', 'HA Customer Care - Internal');
        if(!restricted.contains(u.Profile.Name){
            return;
        }

        Map<Id, Account> accs = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id
            FROM Account
            WHERE Id IN 
                (
                    SELECT AccountId 
                    FROM Contact 
                    WHERE Id IN :contacts
                ) 
                AND ps_BookingOffice__r.Name != :u.ps_BookingOfficeID__c]);
        for(Contact c : contacts){
            if(c.AccountId == null){
                c.addError('You can\'t delete this private contact because we can\'t determine which office they would belong to');
            } else if(accs.containsKey(c.AccountId){
                c.addError('This contact does not belong to your office');
            }
        }
    }
}

